# Extract right part of a character string in R using STRSPLIT and multiply it by 100

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

I'm looking forward to extract the numbers of a character string. Unfortunately, I'm getting the left part of it.

```
Data:
> T3_C2_Z2_Stata_S
     [,1]                  
[1,] "Min.   :-0.0031685  "
```

R-Code:

```
T3_C2_Z2_Stata_S<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(T3_C2_Z2_Stata_S,split=':',fixed=TRUE))[1])*100
```

It is not working because the inner function with `unllist` is returning the following:

```
> T3_C2_Z2_Stata_S
[1] "Min.   "
```

My desired output would be:

```
> T3_C2_Z2_Stata_S
     [,1]                  
[1,] -0.31685
```

Does anyone know how to get this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `str_extract` from the `stringr` package:

```
x <- "Min.   :-0.0031685  "
as.numeric(str_extract(x, "-?\\d+\\.?\\d*")) *100
[1] -0.31685
```

Alternatively, using `str_split` you have to replace `[1]` by `[2]`:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, split = ':', fixed = TRUE))[2])*100
[1] -0.31685
```